# Error: Service(Client(VersionInvalid("cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)")))

Tags: runtime, wasm, substrate-contracts-node, error

Link:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node
- https://use.ink/getting-started/running-substrate

### When I try to run "substrate-contracts-node --dev" I get this error:

```js
substrate-contracts-node --dev

2023-04-08 23:37:38.268  INFO main sc_cli::runner: Substrate Contracts Node    
2023-04-08 23:37:38.269  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ✌️  version 0.23.0-87a3d76c880    
2023-04-08 23:37:38.269  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ❤️  by Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>, 2021-2023    
2023-04-08 23:37:38.269  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Chain specification: Development    
2023-04-08 23:37:38.269  INFO main sc_cli::runner:   Node name: lame-floor-2876    
2023-04-08 23:37:38.269  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Role: AUTHORITY    
2023-04-08 23:37:38.269  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Database: ParityDb at /var/folders/3l/0tn_88cj6wn6yq5cdj8l61w80000gn/T/substrateJESQyD/chains/dev/paritydb/full    
2023-04-08 23:37:38.269  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ⛓  Native runtime: substrate-contracts-node-100 (substrate-contracts-node-1.tx1.au1)    
Error: Service(Client(VersionInvalid("cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)")))
2023-04-08 23:37:38.321  WARN main wasm-runtime: Cannot create a runtime error=Other("cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)"
```

I'm use MAC M1

##### ============================

##### substrate-contracts-node 0.24.0-fe448511262

====

- rustup +nightly show
- Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
- rustup home:  /Users/secoalba/.rustup

```js
installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-2023-03-14-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

aarch64-apple-darwin
wasm32-unknown-unknown

active toolchain
----------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.68.2 (9eb3afe9e 2023-03-27)

Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/secoalba/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-2023-03-14-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

aarch64-apple-darwin
wasm32-unknown-unknown

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin (overridden by +toolchain on the command line)
rustc 1.70.0-nightly (700938c07 2023-04-04)
```

Comment: Looks a lot like these other issues: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/search?q=UnknownOpcode%28192%29